# invalid syntax error : Quine McCluskey Algorithm in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

i'm totally new in python, and here is some code my friend sent it for me, this is Quine-McCluskey Algorithm that provides answer with getting minterms, the code is somehow simple but because i am not exprienced python programmer i have not much ideas for fixing this problem

this is the source code : [Quine-McCluskey (github)](https://github.com/jonghewk/Quine_McCluskey)

```
def find_minimum_cost(Chart, unchecked):
P_final = []
#essential_prime = list with terms with only one 1 (Essential Prime Implicants)
essential_prime = find_prime(Chart)
essential_prime = remove_redundant_list(essential_prime)

#print out the essential primes
if len(essential_prime)>0:
    s = "\nEssential Prime Implicants :\n"
    for i in range(len(unchecked)):
        for j in essential_prime:
            if j == i:
                s= s+binary_to_letter(unchecked[i])+' , '
    print s[:(len(s)-3)] #ERROR  <-------- 

#modifiy the chart to exclude the covered terms
for i in range(len(essential_prime)):
    for col in range(len(Chart[0])):
        if Chart[essential_prime[i]][col] == 1:
            for row in range(len(Chart)):
                Chart[row][col] = 0
```

-

```
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\main.py", line 204
  print s[:(len(s)-3)]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the Error is in this line :     print s[:(len(s)-3)]

Comment: This is python 2 code but you tagged the question with python 3 - what version of python are you using?

Comment: if you use Python 3 then you need `print()` instead of `print` - it means `print( s[:(len(s)-3)] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original author intended for the program to be executed with a python2 interpreter.
He wrote (roughly):

```
print s
```

To execute with a modern python3 interpreter, you would instead need:

```
print(s)
```